# Is having a DNS SERVER on my PC will allow me create my own domain names?

Tags: dns

I am thinking about running a `DNS SERVER` on Ubuntu!

Is having a `DNS SERVER` will allow me create my own domain names and map them in the `Zone File` without buying a domain name from a registrar e.g.(Godaddy.com)?

Comment: Why not just edit `/etc/hosts` file?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean domain names that the rest of the world can see, then no. Part of what you pay for when you register a name is that you'll be pointed out as the owner when other people try to resolve the name.

If you mean domain names that only you can see while running on your own machine, then sure. You can set things up that way.